# Is it possible to get the Feature label name by passing the Plugin Name/ID

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to get the feature name of a particular plugin at the time of un-installation of the plugin.I can get the required plugin name and version using below code.

```
 IRequirement iRequirement = (IRequirement) iterator.next();
 String[] arr = iRequirement.toString().split("\\[|\\]|\\s+");
 IVersionedId versionedId = new VersionedId(arr[0].trim(), arr[1].trim());
```

But,I wanted to get the features name while passing the Plugin-ID or Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know plugin name lets say `"com.my.plugin"`, you could use something like this to get the feature name. It is stored in a dictionary inside the `Bundle`

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle( "com.my.plugin" );
String featureName = bundle.getHeaders().get( org.osgi.framework.Constants.BUNDLE_NAME );
```

In fact you can get also version like :
    `Version version =  bundle.getVersion();`